# cURL web scraping leads to 404 after redirects header 302

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm making my start in this area of web scraping, unfortunnely there aren't many resourses to documentate in the theme, so i came across with this problem.

First of all, i'm trying to make login in a web platform that has plenty of redirection to enter it, i'll try to explain the steps that i noticed.

This way is how i'm sending the data to post in the login form:

```
$headers = array(
    'Referer' => 'url from past step',
    'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);
$respuesta = $this->getPostResponse(
    'this is the first url',
    array(
        'option'=>'credential',
        'target'=>'this is the second url (don't know why is here)',
        'user_id'=>$user,
        'password'=>$contrasena,
        'submit'=>'Enviar'
     ),
     $headers
);
```

After this i receive the following answer:

Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 
Content-Length: 319
```

Content:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        location.href='url that still works';

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So here then i make that location.href

```
$headers = array(
     'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
     'Referer' => 'the url from start',
     'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'
);

$respuesta = $this->getGetResponse('url that still works',$headers);
```

And receive the following response:

Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: THE PROBLEM STARTS WITH THIS URL
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 20 Jan 2018 01:06:05 GMT
```

The answer is what i expected, but the fact that this is a redirection page is what i can't understand, i tried with cURL to no redirect (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false) and so i make the get request 'manually' to that link and didn't work, also it didn't work with the opposite (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true)

No matter if i make cURL to redirect or if i make 'manually' i get this response from that location:

Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

When it should be

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: ANOTHER REDIRECT TO FINAL STEP
```

Maybe the headers are the problem? Or it's the way im facing the redirect? There's someone who could help me find this out?

This is my cURL config:

```
public static $defaultOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "UTF-8",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1
);
```

I made my best to explain my problem, I apologize for the language errors

Comment: You are attempting to login to a site that you do not control. That site may have techniques to defeat an attempt like this.

Comment: Yes, i know that's the challenge i am still using my user and password

Comment: please dont scrape sites that dont want you to.

Comment: I do not understand why you are hating my question. I just asked for a little support

Comment: look into cookies: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_04.htm

Comment: This is actually something i never think, i'm gonna try it, thanks Tim G